# Using Arraylists to store passwords in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm in my first computer programming class and my assignment is to create a program that will allow a user to reserve an airline ticket. This is my first time working with Java GUI and I've so far been successful, except I can't get my program to recognize the entered password. I've pasted my code below. Can someone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks! This is my class:

```
public class OptionGUI extends JPanel  implements ActionListener
{
   ArrayList<String>passworddatabase= new ArrayList();
   ArrayList<String> usernamedatabase= new ArrayList();
   JButton newaccount = new JButton("Create a new account");
   JButton login= new JButton("Login");
   public int response;
  public OptionGUI()
  {

    newaccount.setVerticalTextPosition (AbstractButton.CENTER);
    newaccount.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);
    newaccount.setActionCommand("create");

    login.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    login.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.TRAILING);
    login.setActionCommand("login");
    login.setEnabled(true);

    newaccount.addActionListener(this);
    login.addActionListener(this);

    add(newaccount);
    add(login);
   }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
   {
       if ("create".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
      {

        newaccount.setEnabled(true);
        login.setEnabled(false);

        JPanel logininfo= new JPanel();
        JLabel usernameLbl= new JLabel("Choose a username:");
        JLabel passwordLbl= new JLabel("Choose a password:");
        JTextField username= new JTextField();
        JPasswordField password= new JPasswordField();

        logininfo.add(usernameLbl);
        logininfo.add(username);
        logininfo.add(passwordLbl);
        logininfo.add(password);


        logininfo.setVisible(true);

        int input2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,logininfo, "Create your account:"
                            ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        char[] enteredPassword= password.getPassword();
        char[] enteredPassword2= passwordconfirm.getPassword();
        String newusername= username.getText();
        String newpassword= String.valueOf(enteredPassword);
        String newpassword2= String.valueOf(enteredPassword2);

        String[] options = { "Login", "Cancel" };
        response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Your account has been successfully created! Please login to continue.", "Confirmation",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options,options[0]);                    

            }
        passworddatabase.add(newpassword);
        usernamedatabase.add(newusername);

        }
       if ("loginbutton".equals(e.getActionCommand())|| response==0)
       {  
        login.setEnabled(true);
        newaccount.setEnabled(false);
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        JLabel usernameLbl = new JLabel("Username:");
        JLabel passwordLbl = new JLabel("Password:");
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField passwordFld = new JPasswordField();

        panel.add(usernameLbl);
        panel.add(username);
        panel.add(passwordLbl);
        panel.add(passwordFld);

        panel.setVisible(true);

        int input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, panel, "Enter your password:"
                            ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        String inputPassword= String.valueOf(passwordFld);
        String inputUsername= username.getText();

        for(int i=0; i < passworddatabase.size(); i++) 
        {
         if (passworddatabase.get(i).contains(inputPassword))
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to AIR Ticket Reservation!");
         }

        else
         {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The username or password you entered does not exist.", "Error",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
    }
```

And my driver:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Driver 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    { 

        JFrame option= new JFrame ("Ticket Reservation");
        option.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        option.setSize(500,300);
        option.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        OptionGUI newContentPane= new OptionGUI();
        option.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        option.setVisible(true);
    }             
}
```

It's quite lengthy but much thanks!

Comment: As you said, your code is a bit lengthy, and not many people would be willing to read through all that. Can you isolate the problem to just a couple lines of code (~10 lines or so) then edit your original post?

Comment: You seem to be comparing the entered password against the full password database - so if you do get the code working, user1's password will work for user2. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this issue. How would I fix this? Also, is there any way I can prevent the ArrayList from resetting every time I close the program and re-open it?

Comment: When you get a chance, change your program in two ways. First, never store a password in a Java String. Always use a char array. Strings stay in the system until the garbage collector disposes of them, and who knows when that will happen? Somebody who hacks into your program might see the password. Second, never store a password as is in the database. Always use a hashing function on the value; your database should have one available. And, salt the password before you put it into the database; any book on databases and cryptography will give details. Avoid the dictionary attack.

Comment: Alright. If I used a char array, though, would I be able to store multiple passwords in one array, or would I have to instantiate a new array for each new password? Also, if I closed the program would the char array clear itself out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in the loginButton action command handling you possibly have an issue.. You should be using the value of the JPasswordField and not JPasswordFieldObject itself. I am pretty sure, you didn't mean to write it that way. Please check if that helps.

```
       String.valueOf(passwordFld.getPassword());
```

Try the above line of code for inputPassword String.

```
    String inputPassword= **String.valueOf(passwordFld);**
    String inputUsername= username.getText();

    for(int i=0; i < passworddatabase.size(); i++) 
    {
     if (passworddatabase.get(i).contains(inputPassword))
    {
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I have been trying to fix this problem for a long time and I couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help...if you don't mind could you please mark this one as the answer :P